# Flagged post didn't get re-edited

Tags: discussion, flagging

While going through my usual reviews of posts, I will also check for accessibility, formatting, grammar, etc. I came across [an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/464658/381466) that was quoting a link they provided but the quote was formatted using backticks (`). I proceeded to edit it according to site guidelines.

I happened to be looking through the site several an hour later and noticed that the post had been rolled back. This has happened before on another Stack and proceeded to flag the post for the rollback. I checked on the result of the flag and it was marked as "Helpful" and waited to see the edits correct. To my surprise, it has yet to be edited or rolled back.

Was my flag accidentally marked as "Helpful"? If it was indeed "Helpful", why was no edit/rollback done?

Comment: I'll let a mod come in with an official answer on this, but if it were me, I'd rollback to your edit & leave a comment for the OP on SE's editing policy - https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/editing If a rollback war ensues, then it really has to be a mod who handles it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have been more carefully when handling that flag, thanks for following up (basically I forgot the rollback :-)).

Comment: That's what I thought happened. We get busy sometimes and things fall through the cracks. Thanks.